# Detecting browser launch mode in a npapi plug-in

Tags: npapi

I would like to detect whether my npapi based plug-in is launched in out of process mode(browser is in 64 bit mode) or in in-process mode(browser is in 32 bit mode). Current I use the following code to detect

NSString *processName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];

```
if (processName)
{
    if ( !([processName compare:@"Safari" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) 
        && !([processName compare:@"firefox" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
        && !([processName compare:@"firefox-bin" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
        && !([processName compare:@"Google Chrome" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame))
    {
        // out of process 
    }
}
```

This code would fail if the executable name of the browser fails. Is there another way of checking the browser launch mode?

Comment: This is probably the only way to check what you're asking to check, but as smorgan says, this is completely the wrong approach.  You should really consider looking at FireBreath (http://www.firebreath.org), which would probably be a much lighter learning curve and solves a lot of the issues you are likely to run into.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question is not correct; "OOP" and "64-bit" are not equivalent concepts. Chrome for Mac and Windows are currently 32-bit only, but always runs plugins out of process. Gecko-based browsers like Firefox have hidden prefs to control whether plugins run in or out of process.

More importantly though: a plugin shouldn't care whether it's being run in or out of process; the plugin API doesn't change. What problem are you actually trying to solve that you think you need to know this?

Comment: My Plug-in has two drawing models Core Animation and Core Graphics. If plug-in runs out of process, I load Core Animation drawing model and use Cocoa events otherwise we load Core Graphics model. So I need to detect whether my plug-in is load out of process or not.

Comment: No, all you need to do is use the model negotiation system: <https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI:Models>. Attempting to decide your model by the browser's name, or its process model, or anything other than the model negotiation system, is simply not correct. (It's not even clear to me why you think in-process vs. out-of-process is relevant to that choice, since I don't know of any browsers whose CA+Cocoa or CG+Cocoa support is based on being in or out of process.)